# What is the term for barrier between two cubicles in office?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the term for the the half wall that separates cubicles in an office?

Usage: " I can't see the guy in the next cubicle because of this ___"

Comment: *Partition*, *panel*, *divider*.

Comment: We usually just called them "cubical walls".

Comment: I'd like to paraphrase it to "we are hidden from view in neighboring cubicles". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A [cubicle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubicle) is a partially enclosed office workspace that is separated from neighboring workspaces by **partitions**

They are referred to as:

> **partitions** / **panels** / **dividers**

To see different kinds of partition, you could check this [site](https://www.officefurniture.com/Office-Partitions-Furniture.aspx) out.